# FindMany and looks in any week

Tags: node.js, prisma

the query was like this http://localhost:3000/user/test/week?week=13&year=2023

```
const result = await prisma.test.findMany({
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                    week: value.week,
                    year: value.year
                },
            });
            render(res, 200, statuscodes.OK, result);
```

but its return 0Values of an array, it should have be return all the data at this week

i was expecting that this is will be returning the data at the same week from the query

Comment: share your data,

Comment: Can you please share the `schema.prisma` file so we can reproduce this locally?

Comment: Please check if values `value.week` and `value.year` are proper type. Query params are always strings